# Running espresso test from jenkins using android annotations

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, annotations, android-espresso

I created a simple weather app using android annotations and a test project for this weather app using espresso. Right now I'm trying to run my test from jenkins but i just can't make it work.
I followed this guide (https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Automating-the-Build-in-Jenkins-with-Ant) to create my custom_rules.xml... This is what I get when I start building the app with jenkins....

```
-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     [echo]       Android Annotations is generating code      
     [echo] -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    [javac] Compiling 6 source files to C:\Users\john.tremp\.jenkins\workspace\WeatherApp\bin\classes
    [javac] Note: Resolve log file to C:\Users\john.tremp\.jenkins\workspace\WeatherApp\bin\androidannotations.log
    [javac] Note: Initialize AndroidAnnotations 3.0.1 with options {}
    [javac] Note: Start processing for 2 annotations on 6 elements
    [javac] Note: AndroidManifest.xml file found in parent folder C:\Users\john.tremp\.jenkins\workspace\WeatherApp: C:\john.tremp\.jenkins\workspace\WeatherApp\AndroidManifest.xml
    [javac] Note: AndroidManifest.xml found: AndroidManifest [applicationPackage=com.example.weatherapp, componentQualifiedNames=[com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity_], permissionQualifiedNames=[], applicationClassName=null, libraryProject=false, debugabble=false, minSdkVersion=16, maxSdkVersion=-1, targetSdkVersion=19]
    [javac] Note: Found project R class: com.example.weatherapp.R
    [javac] Note: Found Android class: android.R
    [javac] Note: Validating elements
    [javac] Note: Validating with EActivityHandler: [com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity]
    [javac] Note: Validating with ViewByIdHandler: [textview]
    [javac] Note: Processing root elements
    [javac] Note: Processing root elements EActivityHandler: [com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity]
    [javac] Note: Processing enclosed elements
    [javac] Note: Processing enclosed elements with ViewByIdHandler: [org.androidannotations.model.AnnotationElements$AnnotatedAndRootElements@2c1a8529]
    [javac] Note: Number of files generated by AndroidAnnotations: 1
    [javac] Note: Writting following API classes in project: []
    [javac] Note: Generating class: com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity_
    [javac] Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 225 ms], [Process Annotations = 85 ms], [Generate Sources = 58 ms], [Find R Classes = 26 ms], [Validate Annotations = 14 ms], [Extract Manifest = 11 ms], [Extract Annotations = 9 ms], 
    [javac] Note: Finish processing
    [javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
    [javac] java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DiagnosticSource.setEndPosTable(DiagnosticSource.java:136)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Log.setEndPosTable(Log.java:350)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:670)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:953)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:892)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:921)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1187)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1173)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:859)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [javac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1159)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:935)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [javac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    [javac]     at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [javac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [javac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [javac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:306)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:221)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [javac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    [javac]     at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [javac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\john.tremp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:620: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\john.tremp\.jenkins\workspace\WeatherApp\custom_rules.xml:9: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\john.tremp\.jenkins\workspace\WeatherApp\custom_rules.xml:27: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Does anyone using android annotations and espresso has any experience running the test from jenkins? Or how to set up the environment? Thanks for your help!

Comment: We use Jenkins/Gradle/Espresso/MacOS and that works for us. I haven't tried it on Windows with Ant. Although, it looks like you are trying to compile with Java 8, you might want to try compiling with Java 7. From the above, it doesn't look like it has anything to do with Espresso.

Comment: Yes, I quite agree with you. Do you use Android Annotations in your project?

Comment: No, we do not use android annotations